# No known class method for selector 'myStaticUsername'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object

So I'm trying to access the variable 'username' from another class and append it to a URL as a string. I'm getting the error "No known class method for selector 'myStaticUsername'" and don't really know how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

FirstViewController.h

```
+(NSString *) username;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
static NSString *myStaticUsername = nil;

@implementation FirstViewController

+(NSString *) username{
    return myStaticUsername;
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped.");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {


        myStaticUsername= Textbox.text;
        NSLog(myStaticUsername);
}
```

My ViewController.m class where I'm trying to access it:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *email = [FirstViewController myStaticUsername];

   NSString *website =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.nameofwebsite?un=:%@", email]; //append the username right here
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` you need to change this:

```
NSString *email = [FirstViewController myStaticUsername];
```

to this:

```
NSString *email = [FirstViewController username];
```

`myStaticUsername` is the name of your static `NSString`, but the name of the class method you wrote to access it is `username`.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks!